# iOS – Event Kit programming listen to notifications

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, eventkit

I want to observe changes to the Calendar application so I register for the `EKEventStoreChangedNotification` notification. But do I need to have an `EKEventStore` object  "alive" for me to receive this notification? I'm thinking I'm initializing the `EKEventStore` object in on view controller to retrieve some events. And then I will pop this view controller of the navigation stack and the view controller will be deallocated thus the `EKEventStore` object will be deallocated.

Comment: [@Peter Warbo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/294661/peter-warbo) is your doubt cleared..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to keep the EKEventStore object alive as you are already registering EKEventStoreChangedNotification using EKEventStore object named **eventStore**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(storeChanged:)
                              name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification  object:eventStore];
```

Refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ObservingChanges/ObservingChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH4-SW1) for more clearance of your doubt

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3.x, use like below

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.storeChanged(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.EKEventStoreChanged, object: eventStore)
...
...
...
//Method
func storeChanged(_ nsNotification: NSNotification) {
//do your stuff
}
```